# Create map that show user Location and last user's post

Tags: views, 6, entities, location, javascript

I don't know my question is cheap or good !:(

I want to create a map that shows on users location and last post like [Azadnegar](http://azadnegar.com)'s map or Drupal.org front page.
I know I should use openLayers, CCK, views but I can't build as well as Azadnegar!
I want to know how create map like its map, I mean how can I config our modules.
in this site get user location in registration form in list box,how create like it?

what map her use?How create views?or ...

please explain whit detail !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I had to do the very same thing and followed [this good video by Drupal Therapy](http://drupaltherapy.com/gmap). It uses GMap (API 2) + Location modules instead of Open Layers, but if you're on D6 this is still a good solution. If you enable user-locations and node-locations functionalities in the modules page, you'll find predefined Gmap user/nodes location views. If you need to associate geographic information only on certain content types (and not to all nodes), you'd better enable location-CCK and just add and configure a location field to your desired content type, then create your Gmap view.

Hope it helps you to start with maps in Drupal.